When I start my project, I get this "TypeError: NDFrame.describe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetime_is_numeric'"
When I start my project:
ubuntu@ip-10-0-3-15:~/dash-sample-apps/apps/dash-clinical-analytics$ sudo python3 app.py

I get this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ubuntu/dash-sample-apps/apps/dash-clinical-analytics/app.py", line 58, in <module>   check_in_duration = df["Check-In Time"].describe(datetime_is_numeric=True)
                         TypeError: NDFrame.describe() got an unexpected keyword argument 'datetime_is_numeric'

I tried upgrade in the pandas. I want started my project.

According to the documentation, there is no parameter called "datetime_is_numeric" as found here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html# . What is it that you're trying to do/show? What does "Check-In Time" look like?
